# Angular Material access theme color

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

After some searching through SO and GitHub, I'd just like to get a clarification:
There is NO WAY to access a theme color (or any other theme feature), for example to set a mat-card color:

- one cannot access a variable in scss
- one cannot set a class on the component (like class="mat-purple-with-spots")
- one cannot access the feature through the component API, because most of the time it doesn't expose any theme feature.

There are two options I can see:

- one, go through the hairpulling complexity of rolling a custom theme just for that component
- two, just copy the RGB code and set it in plain dumb CSS on your component

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom theme for main colors "accent, primary, warm".

https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#defining-a-custom-theme

In other scenario, you could have directives to apply at components what add a custom class with your styles and nested css selectors.

Example:

```
<mat-card yourDirectiveForCustomStyles></mat-card>
```

Comment: ok, I mentioned the custom theme as an option. it's an extreme solution -- if I want a card header to be primary (or purple, which is a material color) instead of the default, I need to go through a custom theme all the way to styles.scss. Please go a little through the second option, with the directive: do you know of a way to access colors from the main theme as variables/props?

Comment: You can't access to palette color of material to use theirs colors neither variables, but you can have your custom palette in your app and create styles for override this default styles and apply with a directive.